# Ember each, display list, add group headline for attribute

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I'm trying to wrap my head around this, but I can't seem to find a clean solution. I got this model:

```
// models/person.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  birthDate: DS.attr('date'), // e.g. ISO date => 1.2.1990
  name: DS.attr('string'), // e.g. John Doe
  birthYear: Ember.computed('birthDate', function() {
    return this.get('birthDate').getFullYear(); // => 1990
  })
});
```

and I want the persons.hbs to display it like this:

```
<h4>1990</h4>
<ul>
 <li>John Doe</li>
 <li>Jane Doe</li>
</ul>
<h4>1989</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Jack Doe</li>
</ul>
<h4>1988</h4>
<ul>
 <li>Jim Smith</li>
 <li>Jack Smith</li>
</ul>
```

So basically I want the list of all the persons to be separated by each birth year. I'm thankful for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [this](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-enumerable-no-group-by/3594/2)

```
groupedResults: function () {
  var result = [];

  this.get('content').forEach(function(item) {
    var hasType = result.findBy('type', item.get('type'));

    if(!hasType) {
     result.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({
        type: item.get('type'),
        contents: []
     }));
    }

    result.findBy('type', item.get('type')).get('contents').pushObject(item);
   });

   return result;
}.property('content.[]')
```

And on Template

```
{#each groupedResults}
  <h1>{{type}}</h1>
  {{#each contents}}
     <!-- assuming it has a name -->
     {{name}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that there's an npm package that does exactly that.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-group-by